# Template deduction failing

Tags: c++, templates

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work:

```
#include "itkCovariantVector.h"
#include "itkImage.h"

template <typename TComponent, int NumberOfComponents>
void FillImage(itk::Image<itk::CovariantVector<TComponent,
NumberOfComponents>, 2>* const image,
               itk::Image<itk::CovariantVector<TComponent,
NumberOfComponents>, 2>* const output)
{
  std::cout << "Works." << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char* [] )
{
  typedef itk::Image<itk::CovariantVector<float, 3u>, 2u> ImageType;

  ImageType::Pointer imageSmartPointer = ImageType::New();
  ImageType* image = imageSmartPointer.GetPointer();
  FillImage(image, image);
  return 0;
}
/*
no matching function for call to ‘FillImage(ImageType*&, ImageType*&)’
note: candidate is:
template<class TComponent, int NumberOfComponents> void
FillImage(itk::Image<itk::CovariantVector<TComponent,
NumberOfComponents>, 2u>*, itk::Image<itk::CovariantVector<TComponent,
NumberOfComponents>, 2u>*)
*/
```

The definitions of those class templates are: http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1CovariantVector.html
http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1Image.html

I created the same situation with non-ITK classes, and it works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename TPixel, int Dimensions>
struct Image
{
};

template <typename TComponent, int NumberOfComponents>
struct Vector
{
};

template <typename TComponent, int NumberOfComponents>
void FillImage(Image<Vector<TComponent, NumberOfComponents>, 2 >* const image,
               Image<Vector<TComponent, NumberOfComponents>, 2 >* const output)
{
  std::cout << "Works." << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char* [] )
{
  typedef Image<Vector<float, 3>, 2 > ImageType;

  ImageType* image = new ImageType;
  FillImage(image, image);
  delete image;
  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain what might be the difference?

Comment: Possibly a stupid question: why is the function that does match preceded by `template <typename TPixel> template <typename TScalarPixel>`?

Comment: Could you also post the signature for itk::Image<itk::CovariantVector<float, 3>, 2>::GetPointer()?

Comment: the template<typename TPixel> is because the function template is inside a class template. The ImageType::Pointer is a smart pointer. imageSmartPointer.GetPointer() returns a normal ImageType*.

Comment: OK, from the errors that you posted, there seems to be an issue with `itk::SmartPointer<bla bla bla>::ObjectType`. What is this `ObjectType`? Is it a typedef inside the `itk::SmartPointer` template?

Comment: @MihaiTodor, I have greatly simplified the question - any ideas now?

Comment: Well, now it's clear why the first example fails: `void FillImage` is a function template and you're calling it as a simple function, so the compiler is required to deduce the template parameters `TComponent` and `NumberOfComponents`. See here for details: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/template_argument_deduction.htm Unfortunately, I can't help you figure out why this mechanism fails for these classes. Maybe someone with more experience on templates is willing to go through the documentation that you provided to figure it out...

Comment: Ah, the problem was I had to change the signature from <int NumberOfComponents> to <unsigned int NumberOfComponents> so it matched the definition of the ITK classes.

Comment: Oh... Yeah, I was wondering about those, but I wasn't sure. It can get very hairy once you have so many overloads, especially with the superfluous C++ template syntax. I'm glad you managed to figure it out, though. Good luck with your project! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had to change the signature from `<int NumberOfComponents>` to `<unsigned int NumberOfComponents>` so it matched the definition of the ITK classes.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename TPixel, int Dimensions>
struct Image
{
};

// The deduction works with this
// template <typename TComponent, int NumberOfComponents>
// struct Vector
// {
// };

// The deduction does NOT work with this (unsigned int vs int above)
template <typename TComponent, unsigned int NumberOfComponents>
struct Vector
{
};

template <typename TComponent, int NumberOfComponents>
void FillImage(Image<Vector<TComponent, NumberOfComponents>, 2 >* const image,
               Image<Vector<TComponent, NumberOfComponents>, 2 >* const output)
{
  std::cout << "Works." << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char* [] )
{
  typedef Image<Vector<float, 3>, 2 > ImageType;

  ImageType* image = new ImageType;
  FillImage(image, image);
  return 0;
}
```